# How do I open, write and save a file while avoiding errors?

Tags: java, exception, robustness

I need to erase a file in my program. My solution was to have an `erase()` method that would do that like so:

```
public static void erase(String string) {
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw  = new FileWriter(string);
        fw.write(new String());
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fw.flush();
        fw.close(); 
    }
}
```

Several problems here:

- If the `fw` does not properly initialize (for whatever reason, missing file, invalid persmissions, etc) then when I try to close it in the `finally` block, there is a NullPointerException.
- If I don't have the finally block, then I might be throwing a NullPointerException for the reason above.
- If I close the file inside the try block, then I might leak the resource if the file properly opens, but doesn't properly write.

What other problems am I overlooking and how can I harden this method?

Comment: RandomAccessFile.setLength(0) might be more readable (and possibly more correct since character encodings may contain a BOM character or two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just wrap the finally functionality in an if-statement:

```
if(fw != null){
    fw.close(); 
}
```

This will ensure that if the file was ever opened, then it will be closed.  If it wasn't opened in the first place, then it won't do anything, which is what you want.

Also, I'm not sure if it's just like that for posting, but it's generally not advisable to just print a stacktrace in a catch block and continue ("swallowing" the exception).  You really should let the exception get thrown because this could hide bugs and make tracking them down very hard.

EDIT:  See comment below.

Comment: Uh, guys, flushing already happens within the close statement, no need to perform it right before that.

Comment: @owlstead: Generally it's the implicit flush that can cause an IOException in close(); rather put the flush explicitly in the `try` block, which means it would be truly extraordinary for close to actually throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Include the `flush()` in your main block and have only the `close()` in the catch.  Then check  for null before closing:

```
finally {
    if(fw!=null) { fw.close(); }
    }
```

With the flush in the main block, you can also try/catch the `close` and log or ignore any error:

```
finally {
    if(fw!=null) { 
        try { fw.close(); } catch(Throwable thr) { log.printError("Close failed: "+thr); thr.printStackTrace(); } 
        }
    }
```

or (not generally recommended):

```
finally {
    try { fw.close(); } catch(Throwable thr) {;}
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

The *best* general Java idiom for handling I/O, IMO, is:

```
FileWriter fw=null;
try {
    fw=new FileWriter(string);
    fw.write(new String());
    fw.close();
    fw=null;
    }
catch(IOException ie) {
    // do something real here to handle the exception, or don't catch it at all.
    } 
finally {
    if(fw!=null) { 
        try { fw.close(); } catch(Throwable thr) { thr.printStackTrace(); } // now we're really out of options
        }
    }
```

This has the important effect of allowing the `catch` to catch and handle an exception thrown by `close()` itself.  (The `catch` clause should only be present if you can *handle* the exception in some way; do ***NOT*** catch and ignore, and *generally* you should not simply catch and trace.)

Comment: Catching `Throwable` in the finally-block (and not re-throwing) seems unwise since it would hide potentially serious issues.  Catching NPE would make more sense... but that just seems excessive when you can simply check for null.

Comment: @dhg: Exactly, as my first suggestion does; but then you're left with `throws IOException` as a result of the `close()` if you handle IOException internally; and you have to ask yourself "*if* flush has already been done, then what can I do besides log an error if close fails"?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this is the correct idiomatic way to write your code:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(string);
try {
    fw.write(new String());
    fw.flush();
} catch (IOException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    fw.close(); 
}
```

Explanation:

- If `new FileWriter()` throws an exception, then we don't need to clean up anything. The method exits without executing the `finally`.
- We should put `fw.flush()` in the `try`, not in the `finally`. There are two reasons: If the write failed, then we shouldn't bother flushing. Also, if you put the `flush()` in `finally` and it throws an exception, then the `close()` will be skipped.

Comment: Further comments: 1. `new String()` is the same as `""`. 2. `close()` automatically implies `flush()`. 3. If you want to delete a file, how about `new File(filepath).delete()`? 4. If you want to make the file zero bytes, how about `new FileOutputStream(filepath).close()`?

Comment: This fails to catch the IOException that is thrown from most Writer constructors.